# How to assign commands or keystrokes to the mouse scroll wheel(linux)?

Tags: linux, scrolling, scroll-wheel

I have a lil' problem with a new project. I'd like to find out how to set the ability to change to the next track in a playlist by using ongly the scroll wheel of a standard usb mouse. The objective is to assign a keystroke or a command to both mouse button 4 and mouse button 5 (scroll wheel up and scroll wheel down), so that a program like rythmbox or vlc would skip to the next or previus song in the playlist.
Thanks everybody for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.linux.com/archive/feature/59494 
I found out this solution to my problem. Xbindkeys is great for this use. I assigned to the keystroke "b:5 + Release "the action "rhythmbox-client --previous " ,now it works  !